# Lumia 730 RAM details

Tags: nokia-lumia-730

On a Lumia 730, where can I find RAM usage by my device?

And how do I clean the RAM in my device?

I have found some temporary files to delete in Storage Sense. Is this how I clean RAM?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3376/106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're getting the terms mixed up (memory vs RAM).**

RAM refers to the high speed memory where apps are executed, not stored. The Lumia 730 has 1GB of RAM. The system manages the RAM and there is no option (or reason) to manage this manually.

Storage memory is different. All Windows Phones have built-in storage, anywhere from 4GB to 16GB to even 64GB. Some phones have an SD slot (external storage) which allow you to expand the total storage the phone has.

Storage Sense is the app that allows you to manage the internal (phone) and external (SD card) storage. If you buy an SD card for the Lumia 730, you can use Storage Sense to move apps, games, pictures, etc to the SD card to free up internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

Lumia 730 should come with a 1GB RAM. The easiest way to confirm this is by opening the windows phone store and search for a high end game, say, Modern Combat 5, Modern Combat 4, Brother in Arms 3, NOVA 3 etc. If you could locate any of these games in the store, it means your device is equipped with 1GB RAM. You cannot install the above games on Lumia devices with 512MB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

To easily find out how much total RAM your Lumia has, go to settings → extras+info. Total RAM should be listed there. If it isn't, check the Store for app updates (RAM info was added to extras+info in a recent update).

According to the [official specs](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/phone/lumia730-dual-sim/specifications), the Nokia Lumia 730 has 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Yes, i found in extras+info. It is updated. :)

Comment: And what about the other parts of the question, and the confusion between RAM and storage?

Comment: @NeilTurner Already covered in your answer, no?

Comment: It is, I just don't see the reason for the 2 answers to exist. If you want to amend yours, I'll delete mine :)

Comment: There's no hard limit on answers, so long as they don't directly duplicate each other. Although, yours is the more complete one, and probably should be the one marked as accepted.